# Magento OR query

Tags: magento

I would like to use OR in magento mysql query, I am looking for an equivalent in magento

`where (is_in_stock=0 and show_in_front=1) and (is_in_stock=1 and show_in_front=1)`

I know following can be used for 'OR', but am not sure how to produce an equiavlent query as above;

```
 ->addAttributeToFilter(
     array(
          'attribute' => 'is_in_stock',
          'eq'      => '0',
     ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check this query**

```
//OR Condition
->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'is_in_stock','eq' => '0'),array('attribute' => 'show_in_front','eq' => '1')));
//And Condition
->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => '1'));
->addAttributeToFilter('show_in_front', array('eq' => '1'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked. I have one more question. We are having two attributes check_in_stock and show_in_front. I would like to have magento equivalent query for;
"where (check_in_stock > 0 OR (check_in_stock=0 and show_in_front=1))".

Please help me to find the equivalent magento query.

Comment: Send me first query question

Answer (score 1):

Following is example code for OR condition

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
array(
    array('attribute'=> 'attribute1','like' => 'value1'),
    array('attribute'=> 'attribute2','like' => 'value2'),
    array('attribute'=> 'attribute3','like' => 'value3'),
    )
);
```